# can react-router update the url path but not browser history?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm building an SPA with an image carousel component. A feature I'd like to add is to have shareable links which directly loads a specific image in the carousel. For example, `app.com/carousel/<image-name>`. If the user clicks previous or next, the corresponding image would load in the carousel, and I'd like for the URL path to update to the new image name.

Is it possible to use react-router in this case, for updating the url path, but not update browser history? My reasoning to not update browser history is that there could be a lot of images that the user clicks through. The image carousel is the main component, not each image. There is an image gallery that allows the user to click through to the carousel, so avoiding browser history updates in the carousel is a clean way to track the user's navigation through the app.

So again, is it possible to use react router to update the url path but not browser history? Or is react-router the wrong approach, and there's a better library that suits this task?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I think react-router solves for a different issue/pattern. I don't think it's possible to change the URL in the address bar without using/changing the history stack. The `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` both work with the history object. The `MemoryRouter` keeps a history object in memory and doesn't use the address bar. The point is they all still use *some* history object. I think if you're concerned about long histories because each carousel is its own url then maybe use a redirect on each next/previous slide. This will effect the history state, but only the top/current entry.

Comment: Take a look at [react-swipeable-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable-routes#replace-url-instead-of-push) with replace instead of push and see if that gets you close to what you're after. Otherwise, just use a single `Route` that handles `"carousel/:imageName"` path and do a replace on the next/prev slides.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll take a look!

Comment: It's an interesting question.  It's definitely possibly but probably not "out of the box".  The `history` module which is used by `react-router` (and the underlying browser history object itself) has separate methods to `push` and `replace`.  What you want is for your links to `replace` the history location rather than `push` to it: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md

Comment: I think Drew is right that you should use `Redirect`. If your main concern is that clicking "back" should go back to where they were before the gallery rather than to the previous slide, then you can just make your "previous" and "next" slide links use `Redirect` rather than `Link`.  Note that when going back and then forward, they would arrive on the slide that they most recently viewed last rather than the first slide.  But I think that's a good thing.  https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect